# UITableview delegate is not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

1. I have drag the tableview into a view controller.
2. i have created an outlet property to the table .

   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
3. i have added the delegate in the interface

   UITableViewDelegate

   4.registered the delegate with :
   `tableView.delegate=self;`

and added all functions of a tableview, that usually did worked before :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

And all the others.
the functions are not being called at start.

What am i missing here ?

Comment: They are Data Source Methods, not Delegate Methods.

Comment: I made this mistake a couple of times.  Sooner or later you learn to recognize the symptom.  (If all else fails, *carefully* review the specs.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the tableView's dataSource. These methods appear on the dataSource, not the delegate.

Set `tableView.dataSource=self;` as well, and you should be good to go.

UITableView has two delegates `delegate` and `dataSource` as they handle different areas of focus.

Comment: thats right it did solve it. but why when i have created a class which is a uitableviewcontroller, it worked without it ?

Comment: When you use a UITableViewController, the inner tableView's dataSource and delegate is set to self when UITableViewController loads.

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing one of the following things.

1.Make sure you have set your datasource and delegate of your TableView as your current view controller by Xibs or by code.

2.Do mention your protocal that you have to implement in header of your like below.

```
@interface ViewController()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
```